# Error while using SwiftyJSON to parse parse.com array

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I get an error Swift dynamic typecast failed during run time. Options in the parse table is an Array

```
   if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                    let pf = object as PFObject
                    let name = pf["Question"] as String
                   // let data1 = pf["Options"] as? NSData
                    let jsonData: NSData = pf["Options"] as NSData!
                    let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
                    self.myArray = json.arrayObject as Array<String>
                    println(name)
                    self.question.text = name


                   // println(answers1)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting in the for loop

```
for object in objects as [PFObject]
```

Then you don't have to cast it again inside either.